# Integral Solutions of $x+y=x^2-xy+y^2$

Tags: number-theory, contest-math, diophantine-equations

Find all integral solutions of $$x+y=x^2-xy+y^2$$

A modulo 2 analysis does not work here, only says cannot both be odd.

Comment: Are you trying these contest-math training questions at all yourself? If you are preparing for a contest, then IMO you should spend at least a couple days per question as opposed to post them with 40 minute intervals.

Comment: Yes, I have already tried them :)

Answer (score 2):

Solving $x+y=x^2-xy+y^2$ for $y$ gives you
$$y=\frac{x+1\pm\sqrt{-3x^2+6x+1}}{2}.$$
Here, you have to have
$$-3x^2+6x+1\ge 0\Rightarrow x=0,1,2.$$

Comment: IMO this is not a good solution because it heavily relies on the fact, that there are only squares in the equation and no cubes are quartics or whatever. One should not get used to such a method, when preparing to solve "contest diophantine equations". It is perfectly correct in this case, though.

Comment: Well @MooS I think you're wrong this is nice method. The goal in all contest diophantine equation is to limit the range of one of the variable and then just plug all the possible values. You can do it using modular arithemtic, by guessing right the modulo you'll use, or sometimes you can use a quadratic equation.

Answer (score 1):

Note that: $$(x+y)(x^2 - xy + y^2) = x^3 + y^3$$
$$(x+y)^2 = x^3 + y^3$$

Now let's assume that $x\le y$ and we have:

$$(2y)^2 \ge (x+y)^2 = x^3 + y^3 \ge y^3 \implies 4y^2 \ge y^3 \implies 4\ge y$$

Obviously $y$ must be non-negative number, since otherwise RHS is negative, while LHS is non-negative in the second equation.

Answer (score 0):

Again consider only $x \neq 0 \neq y$.

Only a **Hint** this time: On the one hand the RHS is clearly larger than the LHS, when $xy < 0$. So we can assume $xy > 0$. Then we have $x+y-xy = (x-y)^2 \geq 0$. So the sum of two integers is as least as large as their product. Not too many choices there...