# Integral Solutions of $x+y=x^2−xy+y^2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, diophantine-equations

> Find all integral solutions of
> $x+y=x^2−xy+y^2$

In this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1169631/integral-solutions-of-xy-x2-xyy2), in the last step(of 1st answer) if $-3x^2+6x+1\ge 0$
how did they find the values of $x$ and how to prove that they are the only ones ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just a matter of finding the roots of the quadratic.
$$-3x^2+6x+1\ge0\implies3x^2-6x-1\le0$$
The leading term is positive and the inequality points left, so we know that the range of satisfying $x$ is finite. The roots are $1\pm\frac2{\sqrt3}$, and $x=0,1,2$ are the only integers between those roots, as said in the linked answer.

Comment: @Ishan There is no theorem for that. If the leading term was _negative_, of course, the situation would be reversed.

Comment: @Ishan _There is no theorem!_ It follows from fundamental mathematical reasoning.

Answer (score 0):

Because the leading coefficient of the given quadratic equation is negative, the equation attains negative values for $x$ greater than both roots or less than and positive values for $x$ between the roots. In this particular case, there happens to be three integers between the roots, therefore three integers where the quadratic is non negative.